# Dialog with stroked round background in Flutter

Tags: user-interface, flutter, widget

I want to create a dialog having round cornered background and this background has a 3 pixel stroke, like attached image. I used code below for rounded corners, but how can I add stroke to background?

```
showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Dialog(
             backgroundColor: pinkBackground,
             shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: 
                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
  child: Text(
    "title",

    style: getBodyTextStyle(),
  )
);
        },
      );
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to add `Container` as your `Dialog` child and declare`BoxDecoration` in it

```
 showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
    backgroundColor: AppColors.colorGreen,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius:
    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
    child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent,width: 2),
    borderRadius:
    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
    child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    child: Text(
     "title",
        ),
     ),
    ));
  },
);
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apply locally:

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return Dialog(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
        side: BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: Colors.black),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Text(
          "title",
          style: getBodyTextStyle(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Apply globally:

```
class Application extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final baseThemeData = ThemeData.light();
    final themeData = baseThemeData.copyWith(
      dialogTheme: baseThemeData.dialogTheme.copyWith(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
          side: BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
    );

    return MaterialApp(
      themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
      theme: themeData,
      ...
    );
  }

  void _openDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return Dialog(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Text(
              "title",
              style: getBodyTextStyle(),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The result for both variants:

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

you can add a container as child of another container, and put margin for inner container:

```
child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: const Radius.circular(20.0),
                        topRight: const Radius.circular(20.0),
                        bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(20.0),
                        bottomRight: const Radius.circular(20.0)
                    )
                ),
              child:  Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0)
                    )
                ),
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                child:Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
```

child:Container(height:50,width:100))